# Set the tab item text as bold in WPF tab control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

When I set my tab item font weight to bold, all the controls within that tab become bold. How do I set just the text header of the tab item without affecting the controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did to get it to work. Thanks, SeeSharp, for the hint.

```
            <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ItemTemplate to set template for tab header.
Example:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="UltraBold" Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```