# TabItem.Header Bold When IsSelected

Tags: .net, wpf, tabs, tabitem

Want all the default styling but the Header FontWeight Bold when the TabItem IsSelected
FontWeight Normal when the TabItem is not selected

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <TextBlock>Header Text</TextBlock>
</TabItem.Header>
```

Have found some examples but cannot make any work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `DataTrigger` on TextBlock to see if parent `TabItem` is selected and set `FontWeight` to `Bold` if it evaluates out to be true.

Also you can have that style on `TabItem` as well but since you mentioned `TextBlock` in question i am assuming you are doing more styling with TextBlock in there for Header.

```
<TabItem.Header>
   <TextBlock Text="Header Text">
      <TextBlock.Style>
         <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" 
                            Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </TextBlock.Style>
   </TextBlock>
</TabItem.Header>
```

---

You can put that in style to resuse it for other tabItems -

```
<TabControl>
   <TabControl.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HeaderTextBlockStyle">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
             </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem>
       <TabItem.Header>
          <TextBlock Text="Header Text"
                     Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
       </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
      <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Another Header Text"
                   Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
      </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Works.  Any chance I can apply this once on the Tab and not have to set it for each TabItem?

Comment: Yeah define it in resource section and reuse it for all tabItems. I have updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 5):

```
<XXX.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</XXX.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Item 1" />
        <TabItem Header="Item 2" />
    </TabControl>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: This solution is better than @RohitVats' one, because it's much more reusable, and you only define this once in the Style instead on a per-item basis.

Comment: Thank, this does bold the Header but it also bolds the content.  I only want to bold the Header. Have not yet tested the answer from Rohit Vats

Comment: o'k didn't think of that , i'll edit the answer with a fix a bit later.

Comment: look at the last answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677840/set-the-tab-item-text-as-bold-in-wpf-tab-control

Answer (score 3):

I've used a mix between some answers and this worked perfect for me:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Santiago's answer is very close to what I needed.  I still had to figure out how to attach to the TabControl.  Here is what I ended up with:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <!--TabItems here-->
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style x:Key="ActiveTab" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="header">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource header}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```