# How to apply a Style resource to the Header of a TabItem only

Tags: wpf, styles

In a TabControl I use the following style:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                        Value="Bold" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

I don't know whether it could be easily achieved that the FontWeight is only applied to the header of the TabItem without defining a new (Control)Template for the TabItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it via other posts:

```
<Style x:Key="ActiveTab" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="header">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource header}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I just had this same question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335087/tabitem-header-bold-when-isselected

Comment: Isn't this solution somewhat more clear/practival then yours?

Comment: Yes and no.  If I put a textblock in the header then yours fails.

Comment: I see, although the Header already has a textblock, so there's no need to replace that with your own instance?

Comment: Try and put a line break in without a textblock